# Repeat Row Values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have the following data:

```
with source (Account,AccountNumber,Indentation) as
(
select 'INCOME STATEMENT',1000,0 union all
select 'REVENUE',1100,0 union all
select 'Revenue - Aircon',1110,1 union all
select 'Revenue - Consumer Goods',1120,1 union all
select 'Revenue - Spares',1130,1 union all
select 'Revenue - Accessories',1140,1 union all
select 'Revenue - Sub Stock',1150,1 union all
select 'Revenue - Services',1160,1 union all
select 'Revenue - Other',1170,1 union all
select 'Revenue - Intercompany',1180,1 union all
select 'Revenue - Delivery Charges',1400,1 union all
select 'COST OF SALES',1500,0 union all
select 'COGS - Aircon',1510,1 union all
select 'COGS - Consumer Goods',1520,1 union all
select 'COGS - Spares',1530,1 union all
select 'COGS - Accessories',1540,1 union all
select 'COGS - Sub Stock',1550,1 union all
select 'COGS - Services',1560,1 union all
select 'COGS - Other',1570,1 union all
select 'COGS - Intercompany',1580,1 union all
select 'COS - Sub Stock Stock Adjustments',1610,1 union all
select 'COS - Sub Stock Repairs',1620,1 union all
select 'COS - Consumables & Packing Materials',1810,1 union all
select 'COS - Freight & Delivery',1820,1 union all
select 'COS - Inventory Adj - Stock Count',1910,1 union all
select 'COS - Inv. Adj - Stock Write up / Write down',1920,1 union all
select 'COS - Provision for Obsolete Stock (IS)',1930,1 union all
select 'COS - Inventory Adj - System A/c',1996,1 union all
select 'COS - Purch & Dir. Cost Appl A/c - System A/c',1997,1 union all
select 'GROSS MARGIN',1999,0 union all
select 'OTHER INCOME',2000,0 union all
select 'Admin Fees Received',2100,1 union all
select 'Bad Debt Recovered',2110,1 union all
select 'Discount Received',2120,1 union all
select 'Dividends Received',2130,1 union all
select 'Fixed Assets - NBV on Disposal',2140,1 union all
select 'Fixed Assets - Proceeds on Disposal',2145,1 union all
select 'Rebates Received',2150,1 union all
select 'Rental Income',2160,1 union all
select 'Sundry Income',2170,1 union all
select 'Warranty Income',2180,1 union all
select 'INTEREST RECEIVED',2200,0 union all
select 'Interest Received - Banks',2210,1
)

select
    Account
,   AccountNumber
,   Indentation
from    source;
```

Using the following script:

```
with s as (
select
    iif(Account like 'Total%',null,iif(Indentation=0,Account,null)) Header
,   iif(Account like 'Total%',null,iif(Indentation=1,Account,null)) SubHeader1
,   *
from    Source
)

select
    Header
--, case lag(Header) over (order by [Account Number]) when Header then isnull(Header,lag(Header) over (order by [Account Number])) else Header end
,   SubHeader1
,   [Account Number]
,   Indentation
from    s
```

I'm able to split the columns like this:

[image: Current Results]

I need to be able to report the Header Column to look like this:

[image: Expected Results]

I tried doing it using LAG(), but it doesn't work, how would I script this?

Comment: I'm not sure what about your question is about T-SQL or SQL Server here; It seems like you're asking how to format the data in your presentation layer. That has nothing to do with the database layer.

Comment: I need to have this data split this way so I can create a view off it. I cannot use excel as my source for reporting - I need to use SQL

Comment: But you have the SQL, no? So why can't you create the `VIEW`?

Comment: I need it repeat the values for each row, that way I can build a pivot off it...

Comment: Repeat what rows? All of them? Just `JOIN`/`APPLY` to a 2 row tally. You aren't explaining the problem here.

Comment: The Header Column... as shown in my expected results... and unfortunately I don't know how to do what you're suggesting - please share your knowledge? :)

Comment: You need `last_value` with `ignore nulls` - unfortunately that isn't supported in SQL Server but if you use those search terms you will find workarounds

Comment: also you should have another column to link the header with its sub categories.

Comment: I'm not following what you mean @AliFidanli?

Comment: Revenue - Aircon is the subcategory of REVENUE is it correct ?

Comment: What makes the header link up with its respective sub-rows? Remember that tables have no inherent ordering, you *need* an `ORDER BY`

Comment: If you modify your dataset a little, you could use the T-SQL function ROLLUP. See https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-rollup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one option. I created a Group for each header and then used it to grab the first in that group that had an Indention = 0.  Tack this on to your source CTE:

```
,CTE2 AS
(
select
    iif(Account like 'Total%',null,iif(Indentation=0,Account,null)) Header
,   iif(Account like 'Total%',null,iif(Indentation=1,Account,null)) SubHeader1
, SUM(CASE WHEN Indentation = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY AccountNUmber) H1
,   *
from    Source
)

SELECT T2.Header, t1.SubHeader1, t1.AccountNumber, t1.Indentation
FROM CTE2 t1
CROSS APPLY(SELECT MAX(t3.HEADER) HEADER FROM CTE2 T3 where t3.H1 = T1.H1 and T3.Indentation = 0 ) T2
ORDER BY t1.AccountNumber
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you @JMabee!